# SSRS Web Config - maxRequestLength

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

Can someone happen to let me know what the maximum value that can be set for maxRequestLength in the SSRS web.config file.  I currently have it set to 2097151 but if I increase it any further the SSRS Reports homepage stops working and just displays "Error" I have restarted SSRS through the service as well as the config manager but nothing seems to work, can anyone assist?  The location of the file that I am editing is "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer"

Thanks

Comment: And when you get this error, is anything logged to the Event Viewer or the IIS log files or anywhere else? Anyway, `maxRequestLength` is an IIS thing, and it's not clear to me that any specific limit is set, if I'm looking in [the right place](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: This value is not set in SSRS's web.config out of the box and you should not have an issue unless you are uploading a huge .RDL file. What is it that you think is causing the request size to be surpassed?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, underscore_d, as Ross mentioned this is not set by default, I had to set it for a previous report and no I cant find any reference to the Error.  It just says "Error" when I go to the home location of my reports.  Unfortunately I think it is just down to the size of the report, currently it stands at 33 tables that are being exported to Excel 2003 to form 33 tabs, completely against my better judgement but I have been overruled and I am having to use Excel 2003 so they can view the report over and iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what was the issue, though I had set the maxRequestLength within the relevant config files in SSRS, I had to also amend the Limit Size set in IIS for the SMTP, once I had increased the size here everything worked fine.
I think there was some initial confusion on the error message due to getting a similar one before based on the config file.

Comment: Yes, that is a hard cap at your smtp server. The only configuration values in ssrs's web configuration file that you may likely change is related to timeouts, not size.